# SQL DateTime Conversion (1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I get the following in SQL from a DATETIME.

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z
```

Should I convert this to NVARCHAR or is there a specific datetime value?

Comment: The SQL Server `datetime` type is only accurate to 1/300 seconds, so milliseconds will be rounded to 0, 3, or 7. The `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, or `time` provide up to 100-nanosecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select Convert(varchar(100),datetimeCol,127)
  from tab
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @DateTime2 datetime2 = '1970-01-01 00:00:00.001'
Select Convert(varchar(23),@DateTime2,127)+'Z'
```

Returns

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z
```